# Having trouble generating test X509Certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, makecert

I'm having problems creating a test X509Certificate in my store that I can use in WCF.  All of the certificates I create have the same result when I try to use it in the WCF channel factory - "The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate".

```
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyClientCert");
```

I've tried putting the certificate in LocalMachine, having it self-signed vs. a test CA.  Nothing helps, the certificate always has the property HasPrivateKey equal to false.

**UPDATES:** 
I've gotten past the above problem, by following the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650751.aspx.  However, I'm onto a new problem with the certificate now generating a new error when I try to send the message to the queue.  The error is:

An error occurred while sending to the queue: A cryptographic function failed. (-1072824272, 0xc00e0030).Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. If you are sending to a local queue, ensure the queue exists with the required access mode and authorization.

Again, the process works if I use a real cert instead of a test one, so it seems like it has to be something related to the certificate.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702621.aspx

Comment: your cert is false generated, probably for signing not keyexchange

Comment: I'm using the -sky exchange... parameter.  The link you provided is good, but still doesn't provide me with a solution.

Comment: how do you export from the pfx?

Comment: Posted updates above.  I'm not exporting anything from a pfx.  I generate the cert and revocation list, import them into the store, then generate a client cert directly.  No exporting at all.